# Trying to auto fill textboxes with by selecting an item in combobox. Gets an error when form opens.

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, combobox

I have this stored procedure that gets the product table with provided parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DisplayProductParameter @id nvarchar(100) 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name, P.product_price, T.[type_name], T.[type_fee], T.[type_id] 
    FROM Product P 
    INNER JOIN [Product Type] T ON P.[type_id] = T.[type_id]
    WHERE P.product_id = @id
END;
```

GO

I call it with this function in C#

```
public SqlCommand InitSqlCommand(string query, CommandType commandType)
    {
        var Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        Sqlcommand.CommandType = commandType;
        return Sqlcommand;
    }
```

Then I store it in a DataTable

```
public DataTable GetData(SqlCommand command)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = command };
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Then this is how I get the DataTable

```
public DataTable DisplayProductParameter()
    {
        string getProductIdParam = "DisplayProductParameter";
        var command = Connection.InitSqlCommand(getProductIdParam, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", P.Id); 
        return Connection.GetData(command);
    }
```

This is how I should autofill textboxes whenever I click on the combobox

```
private void cmbProductId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            p.Id = cmbProductId.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dtbProduct = po.DisplayProductParameter();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtbProduct.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                txtProductType.Text = dtbProduct.Rows[i]["type_name"].ToString();
                txtPrice.Text = dtbProduct.Rows[i]["product_price"].ToString();
                txtProductName.Text = dtbProduct.Rows[i]["product_name"].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

But I get this error message at the start of the form

> Procedure or function 'DisplayProductParameter' expects parameter
>   '@id', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Logically your code seems correct.
In order to get more information on where and why this is happening, could you add a breakpoint on this line:

```
public DataTable DisplayProductParameter()
    {
        string getProductIdParam = "DisplayProductParameter";
        var command = Connection.InitSqlCommand(getProductIdParam, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     -->command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", P.Id); 
        return Connection.GetData(command);
    }
```

and run in **debugging mode** to see what the value of `P.Id` is. It could be passing a null or empty string value into the procedure.